# In ViM what is Buffer 0?

Tags: vim, buffer

The vim commands `buflisted(0)` and `bufexists(0)` return true if I have single file open.

I don't understand this because the output of `ls` shows that file as buffer 1 (and `buflisted(1)` and `bufexists(1)` also returns true).  And if I try any buffer operation on buffer 0 I get the error message `Zero count`.

This seems like a special buffer but I can't find any information that tells me what buffer 0 is used for.  Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a really good time to go look into the source code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `0` is explained in `:help bufname()`. It's the "alternate buffer" of the current buffer.

Comment: I can't find that documentation, but is true from the code: `if (nr == 0) nr = curwin->w_alt_fnum;` (in buflist_findnr)

Comment: Do you like spelunking? "bufname({expr}): If {expr} is a Number, that buffer number's name is given. Number zero is the alternate buffer for the current window."

Comment: I was thinking of digits so referencing '0' as the string 'zero' sabotaged my searching efforts.  Thanks for the info...

Comment: @romainl Yeah I like spelunking (`cd /tmp;apt-get source vim;cd vim*;ctags -R .;vim +tj/buflisted` - done). Anyways, I missed it because I was looking for digits too :)